# SQL - Division and Subquery Aliasing

Tags: sql

I am trying to do some calculations on some SQL result sets, and return the values that satisfy a condition (namely rows of these calculations where the result is less than 0.9). When compiling, I get "Each derived table must have its own alias".

I'm hoping I've kept it simple enough.

```
SELECT 1.0*(sum1 - sum2 - sum3)/sum3 AS ratio FROM 
 (SELECT SUM(P.MKT_VAL) AS sum1 FROM PMA_POSITION P WHERE P.EFF_DATE = DATEADD('dd',-1,sysdate) GROUP BY P.ACCT_CD),
 (SELECT SUM(T.EXEC_AMT) AS sum2 FROM PMA_TRANSACTION T WHERE T.TRADE_DATE < DATEADD('dd',-1,sysdate) AND T.TRADE_DATE > DATEADD('dd',-DAY(sysdate)-1,sysdate) AND T.TXN_TYP_CD = 'CASH' GROUP BY T.ACCT_CD),
 (SELECT SUM(P.MKT_VAL) AS sum3 FROM PMA_POSITION P WHERE P.EFF_DATE = DATEADD('dd',-DAY(sysdate)-1,sysdate) GROUP BY P.ACCT_CD) 
WHERE ratio>0.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the aliases and `JOIN` conditions

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT 1.0*(sum1 - sum2 - sum3)/sum3 AS ratio 
  FROM 
  (
      SELECT ACCT_CD, 
             SUM(P.MKT_VAL) AS sum1 
      FROM PMA_POSITION P 
      WHERE P.EFF_DATE = DATEADD('dd',-1,sysdate) 
      GROUP BY P.ACCT_CD
  ) t1
  JOIN (
      SELECT ACCT_CD, 
             SUM(T.EXEC_AMT) AS sum2 
      FROM PMA_TRANSACTION T 
      WHERE T.TRADE_DATE < DATEADD('dd',-1,sysdate) AND 
            T.TRADE_DATE > DATEADD('dd',-DAY(sysdate)-1,sysdate) AND 
            T.TXN_TYP_CD = 'CASH' 
      GROUP BY T.ACCT_CD
  ) t2 ON t1.ACCT_CD = t2.ACCT_CD
  JOIN (
      SELECT ACCT_CD, 
             SUM(P.MKT_VAL) AS sum3 
      FROM PMA_POSITION P 
      WHERE P.EFF_DATE = DATEADD('dd',-DAY(sysdate)-1,sysdate) 
      GROUP BY P.ACCT_CD
  ) t3  ON t2.ACCT_CD = t3.ACCT_CD
) t
WHERE t.ratio>0.9
```